# Early User Space Init Not found

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, initramfs, init, kernel-panic

I have been compiling a kernel for my Android device and there is this problem that I have encountered.

I have ported the kernel from `v3.10.108` to `3.18`.

I have got the kernel to last part and solved almost every issue it had.

The place I am getting stuck at is in the early user space init where it loads the rootfs but for that to happen.

I need the `/init` binary to execute but is fails and does not find any init file.

I have tried adding bootargs but they have just failed

```
[    1.147003] Freeing alternatives memory: 112K
[    1.147072] Failed to execute /init (error -2)
[    1.147093] Failed to execute /init
[    1.147114] Failed to execute /init (error -2).  Attempting defaults...
[    1.147172] Kernel panic - not syncing: No working init found.  Try passing init= option to kernel. See Linux Documentation/init.txt for guidance.
```

Above message is what I get each time.

Can Someone Explain what I am doing wrong or something I am missing?

Source of my kernel: https://github.com/tejasudupa/3.18-kernel-kenzo

I have added all the proper configs but still it fails.